# Image download from mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

i need to give my users the opportunity to download all the images I display in my project. images are displayed from a mysql query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT tl.customername, tl.visitdate, tl.employeename, pz.webpath from table tl
                    inner join pictures pz on pz.visitid = tl.visitid and pz.groupid = tl.groupid
                    inner join agenti ag on ag.idh = tl.employeeid
                    WHERE tl.visitdate >= '$from' AND tl.visitdate <= '$to' 
                    AND tl.employeename like '$r_employee' 
                    AND tl.customerowner like '$r_customer'
                    AND tl.customername like '$r_customername' 
                    AND tl.visitdate like '$r_date' 
                    group by pz.webpath order by tl.customername") or die(mysql_error());
while( $associate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                                echo '<li> <figure>
                                          <img src="../core/includes/timthumb.php?src='.$associate['webpath'].'&w=200&h=200" />
                                          <figcaption>
                                              <h3>'.$associate['customername'].'</h3>
                                              <h6>'.$associate['employeename'].'</h6>
                                              <h6>'.$associate['visitdate'].' </h6>
                                     '; 
                                echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="'.$associate['webpath'].'" title=" '.$associate['visitdate'].' / '.$associate['customername'].'">Big picture</i></a>';
                                echo '</figcaption>
                                      </figure>
                                  </li>';
                            $zip->addFromString(pathinfo ( urldecode($associate['webpath']), PATHINFO_BASENAME), urldecode($associate['webpath']));
                            }
```

How can i add a download button which will save all the images as zip on user computer?

Comment: What's in the result ? actual image data or just an URL ?
depending on how much users/images/servers you have this might be a bigger problem than you expect it to be. if you give more details about that I can give you a proper solution

Comment: returns url in a grid with thumb (timthumb) -> click -> big picture (fancybox). i need to download all the pictures that shows in a grid but at full resolution.

Comment: that's perfect, and are all the pictures on the same server ? or do you have to fetch them too from other places?

Comment: all pictures on the same server and the same folder. i managed to create the zip but images cannot be oppened. i have update my script.

Comment: they won't be opened cause you're adding URLS to the archive not the actual images, you're also limiting your SQL query to 10 results, if that's the situation and they're all in the same directory, would it be a better solution to avoid the database access and just zip that directory right away ? if that works for you let me know i'll create an answer with how to do that

Comment: i have update my post with my real code. so, resulted images came from the query. that resulted images i need to download, because in my folder are over 10gb pictures. if you can give me a solution will be much appreciated.

Comment: ok that's more clear to me, last thing, is `$associate['webpath']` an absolute or relative URL ? can you show an example of that ?

Comment: absolute url. in db i have a table "poze" with two columns, picturespath = d:\pictures\pictures_name.jpg, and another column webpath = http://192.168.0.1/pictures/pictures_name.jpg

Comment: great, i just wrote an answer, post your questions under it if it doesn't work

Comment: where's your aggregate function? And under what circumstances can something be LIKE something else, and not actually EQUAL to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot and with the help of Kate and Mostafa Torbjørn Berg I manage to solveit.So, my final code look like`s this:

```
<?php
$files = array();
....
$query = mysql_query("SELECT tl.customername, tl.visitdate, tl.employeename, pz.webpath from table tl
                    inner join pictures pz on pz.visitid = tl.visitid and pz.groupid = tl.groupid
                    inner join agenti ag on ag.idh = tl.employeeid
                    WHERE tl.visitdate >= '$from' AND tl.visitdate <= '$to' 
                    AND tl.employeename like '$r_employee' 
                    AND tl.customerowner like '$r_customer'
                    AND tl.customername like '$r_customername' 
                    AND tl.visitdate like '$r_date' 
                    group by pz.webpath order by tl.customername") or die(mysql_error());
while( $associate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                                echo '<li> <figure>
                                          <img src="../core/includes/timthumb.php?src='.$associate['webpath'].'&w=200&h=200" />
                                          <figcaption>
                                              <h3>'.$associate['customername'].'</h3>
                                              <h6>'.$associate['employeename'].'</h6>
                                              <h6>'.$associate['visitdate'].' </h6>
                                     '; 
                                echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="'.$associate['webpath'].'" title=" '.$associate['visitdate'].' / '.$associate['customername'].'">Big picture</i></a>';
                                echo '</figcaption>
                                      </figure>
                                  </li>';
        $files[] = $associate['webpath'];
                            } ;
        $zipname = "download/".$_SESSION["user_name"]."". '-Picture-' ."".time().".zip"; //create zip name using user sesion+Picture+timestamp
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE); // create zip file and overwrite if exist => if timestamp is used, no need for overwrite
            foreach ($files as $file) { // take each picture from query and insert in zip
                $zip->addFromString(pathinfo ( urldecode($file), PATHINFO_BASENAME), file_get_contents($file)); } // all pictures will be placed in main folder using their original name
                $zip->close(); //closing zip
                ...
    ?>          
// creating download link for the created zip
<div > <a href ="<?php echo $zipname ?>" > Download pictures </a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can using ZipArchive http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php for create a ZIP file like this:

```
$files = array();
while( $associate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 //....//
 $files[] = $associate['blob'];
};
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
(....) //header
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the file's path, you were using the URL, it may also be useful to read the server's error log to see what the issue is, but this code should work for you, you basically iterate over the results and add the `picturespath` column to your zip archive, let me know if that doesn't work !

```
$zip->open("foo.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);

while( $associate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $zip->addFile($associate['picturespath']);
}

$zip->close();
```

also make sure you cache the zip output someway so you avoid recreating lots of zip files when you can, the least you can do is simply save the archive name as the user's id, and before doing all the creation check if you have a zip with the current user's id first, if so then just serve them the created file already.

Comment: thanks, i finaly succesed based on your answer and Kate sugestions. I will post my final solution soon. thx again.